# Free Pascal: Excess characters from previous input is written to the file

Tags: file, file-handling, freepascal

I'm working on a program to create a simple database, and I'm encountering a problem starting from the second input.

[Running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RipDq.png)

As you can see, I'm experiencing a problem where the second and third entries contain excess characters carried over from the previous inputs that have already been written to the file.

```pascal
program filegen;
type
  fileRecord = Record
    recordName: string[59];
    recordCount: longint;
  end;

var
  myRecord: fileRecord;
  f: file of fileRecord;
  name: string[59];
  counter: longint;

begin
  {$I-}

  if ParamCount <> 1 then
  begin
    writeln('Please specify at least ONE file name to continue. Aborting...');
    halt(1);
  end;

  assign(f, ParamStr(1));
  rewrite(f); 

  if IOResult <> 0 then
  begin
    writeln('Can''t open or create the file: ', ParamStr(1));
    halt(1);
  end;
  
  write('Enter the name of the record: ');
  while not Eof do
  begin
    readln(name);
    if Length(name) = 0 then
    begin
      writeln('The name is empty. Please enter the name to continue.');
      readln;
      continue;
    end;

    write('Enter the number: '); 
    readln(counter);

    if IOResult <> 0 then
    begin
      writeln('Please enter the correct number to continue.');
      readln;
      continue;
    end;

    myRecord.recordName := name;
    myRecord.recordCount := counter;

    write(f, myRecord);

    write('Enter the name of the record: ');
  end; 
  close(f);
end.
```

I tried to clear the `recordName` inside the Record and the `name` varibale itself before the `write` procedure with no success.
Maybe I should clear some internal buffers before attempting to write to the file.
My FPC version is 3.2.2.

Comment: see the example after: "It is worth noting that otherwise strings are internally regarded as arrays.[fn 3] .", (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Pascal_Programming/Strings#Index), which tries to explain that you cannot change the length of an already existing string.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't try to change the length of any arrays. Could you clarify what did you mean?

Comment: Sorry, it's been too long since I did do something in Pascal, but your problem has to do with the definition of your variable (which is a [ShortString](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Shortstring) ), and the (internal) workings of those, see: https://onlinegdb.com/Vr3mUN54A, and note the output of the second line...

Comment: Yeah, I see now. Does it mean that I should iterate through every element in the string and fill it with "NUL" ASCII chars before writing? Is this solution would be effective? I just tried this and it works.

Comment: Are you sure that something is not working? Did you try to read back what you wrote on the disk, using the same record (i.e. read from "file of fileRecord")?

Comment: Yes, I did indeed read the contents of the file using the hexdump utility. You can view the result in the screenshot I have provided. I'm not entirely certain that I fully understood what did you mean.

Comment: See my answer. You can not use hexdump to "decode" a binary file. You use hexdump too see the content: looking at it you can "decode" (you or a program for you).

Answer (score 1):

you are wrong: everything is working perfectly, and your program is correct. Shortstrings in pascal contain the length of the string, in the first byte. If you hexdump the file you create (mine for example):

```
00000000  07 72 65 63 6f 72 64 31  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.record1........|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  04 72 65 63 32 72 64 31  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.rec2rd1........|
```

you notice the first record "07 record1". That 07 is the length of the string "record1". The second record (last line of the dump) shows "04 rec2rd1". The length is 4, and the string is "rec2", which is correct. The "rd1" following "rec2" is garbage, to be ignored. This file, if parsed by pascal, yelds correct results. If you try to parse it with some other tool, you should adhere to the "pascal short string format" which states that first byte specify the length of the string contained in the subsequent bytes, and all the rest must be discarded.

With this simple program:

```
type
  fileRecord = Record
    recordName: string[59];
    recordCount: longint;
  end;

var
  myRecord: fileRecord;
  f: file of fileRecord;
  name: string[59];
  counter: longint;

begin
  {$I-}

  if ParamCount <> 1 then begin
    writeln('Please specify at least ONE file name to continue. Aborting...');
    halt(1);
  end;

  assign(f, ParamStr(1));
  reset(f);

  while not eof(f) do begin
    read(f, myrecord);
    writeln(myrecord.recordname, ^I, myrecord.recordcount)
  end;

  close(f);
end.
```

you can read back what you wrote, and for the file above, it displays:

```
   /tmp$ ./testdump  prova.txt
   record1 1
   rec2    2
```

Even without looking at the implementation, it is reasonable to believe that (free) pascal "works": if you assign a value to a string, than that string will contain what you wrote into it. What happened, and misleaded you, is that writing a shorter string into a longer one does *not* clear the remaining part: why that should be done? simply a waste of CPU!

A note: writing NULs (or #0 in pascal) **does not** clear or terminate the string, it simply puts some (valid) char inside the string. NULs in pascal strings are valid characters, it is the C language that, by convention, terminates strings with a NUL. You have to care about NUL only when passing pascal strings to C routines but, most of the time, this is managed by freepascal runtime automatically.

Another note: trying to polish the string with

```
for i := 1 to length(myRecord.recordName) do
  myRecord.recordName[i] := #0;
```

does not do what you think. It clears the valid characters of the string, but not the remaining (garbage) part. Applied to "04 rec2rd1" it would produce "04 00 00 00 00 rd1", i.e. it will not clear the garbage. Instead:

```
FillChar(myRecord.recordName, SizeOf(myRecord.recordName), #0);
```

would (correctly) clear all the buffer, because sizeof() is the size of the buffer (max length of the string +1). It also zeroes the length of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I just wanted to emphasize that it was important to me to exclude any excess garbage bytes from the written string. The FillChar function works perfectly fine in achieving this. As you can see in the screenshot of my answer, that was added lately, the 'Length' bytes remain in the correct position and are accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Luuk I figured out that I can iterate through the `recordName` variable using `for` loop and fill it with `NUL` ASCII chars before assigning new value.

```
for i := 1 to length(myRecord.recordName) do
  myRecord.recordName[i] := #0;
```

Also I can use `FillChar` procedure to fill the string with the `NUL` chars.

```
FillChar(myRecord.recordName, SizeOf(myRecord.recordName), #0);
```

But I'm not sure if these are most effective ways to handle this problem.

The final code look like this

```pascal
program filegen;
type
  fileRecord = Record
    recordName: string[59];
    recordCount: longint;
  end;

var
  myRecord: fileRecord;
  f: file of fileRecord;
  name: string[59];
  counter: longint;

begin
  {$I-}

  if ParamCount <> 1 then
  begin
    writeln('Please specify at least ONE file name to continue. Aborting...');
    halt(1);
  end;

  assign(f, ParamStr(1));
  rewrite(f); 

  if IOResult <> 0 then
  begin
    writeln('Can''t open or create the file: ', ParamStr(1));
    halt(1);
  end;
  
  write('Enter the name of the record: ');
  while not Eof do
  begin
    readln(name);
    if Length(name) = 0 then
    begin
      writeln('The name is empty. Please enter the name to continue.');
      readln;
      continue;
    end;

    write('Enter the number: '); 
    readln(counter);

    if IOResult <> 0 then
    begin
      writeln('Please enter the correct number to continue.');
      readln;
      continue;
    end;

    FillChar(myRecord.recordName, sizeof(myRecord.recordName), #0);

    myRecord.recordName := name;
    myRecord.recordCount := counter;

    write(f, myRecord);

    write('Enter the name of the record: ');
  end; 
  close(f);
end.
```

And the result when reading the file with the hexdump is looking like this.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkuwD.png)